# Why is my solid and wireframe behave like this?

Tags: 3d-view

My solid and wireframe has been behaving like this while my eevee and cycles still function normally. Here I can only see what is inside that weird light gray thing, while my eevee viewport function normally. [image: Here I can only see what is inside that weird light gray thing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. "**Clipped**" in the title of the viewport indicates this:

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again to remove clipping

[More info about viewport clipping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html)